# Status false Transaction mined but execution failed - Donatio contract

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, ethereumjs, error

I'm trying to deploy my donating contract on FTM testnet in Remix. It compiles successfully, but when I run the donation function, I got this error: `status: false Transaction mined but execution failed.`

Here's my code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract donateMoney {
    address public caller;
    address public receiver;
    uint256 public totalDonations;
    uint256 public value;

    constructor(uint256 _value) {
        caller = payable(msg.sender);
        value = _value;
        receiver = payable(address(this));
    }

    function getTotalDonations() public view returns (uint256) {
        return totalDonations;
    }

    function donate() public payable {
        (bool success, ) = receiver.call{value: value}("");
        require(success, "Failed to send money");
    }
}
```

Here's what I'm inputing in remix:
[image: Remix input]

What can I do to get rid of this error?
Also I'm getting a gas cost warning but the gas cost in the transaction itself turns to be lot lower than the limit:

`gas    3000000 gas`
`transaction cost   365697 gas`

Comment: Note: the wallet address is mine

Answer (score 0):

You get the gas cost warning, because it is not possible to estimate failing transactions.

To test why your transaction is reverting it is easiest to test against the remix integrated network, as they provide more information (e.g. revert message).

In general you code will not work as `donate` send eth to `receiver` which is set to the contract itself in the constructor, but the contract cannot receive eth. Here more info on how to receive eth with fallback function: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html#receive-ether-function

**Edit:**

Regarding the deployment error in Remix: When you want to send money along with any function you need to declare it `payable`. The same applies to your `constructor`.

Therefore to deploy your contract and sent along ether you need to adjust it to look like this:

```js
constructor(uint256 _value) payable {
  caller = payable(msg.sender);
  value = _value;
  receiver = payable(address(this));
}
```

Some more general comments:
The `value` field that you set in remix (which you also see in your screenshot), is not a function parameter. If you want to "read" this value you need to use `msg.value`. This field will return how much ether was send along with the function call (see the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) for more info)

Comment: Created a receive function, looks like this now:
```
event Received(address, uint);
    receive() external payable {
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
```

But still getting the same error.

Comment: Also I don't know why, but when I try to run it on Remix integrated network, i get this error when deploying:

`creation of donateMoney errored: VM error: revert.

revert
 The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.`

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Solved already with your fixes + alternating accounts when running function, 'cause i ended up trying to send ether to the same account and got errors. Thanks for helping, I dont have rep to upvote yet but txs.